# iOS Build Failed : error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening RegoReactNative.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I have run "npm start run" and getting error like...

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening RegoReactNative.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.